# zooming animation problem in ScrollView - Ipad

Tags: ipad, uiscrollview, core-animation, zooming, uisplitviewcontroller

In my app, I have a split screen in which the detail view is a scrollview. I have 5 tables which are subviews of my scrollview in which 3 table views are side by side on top and 2 table views are side by side on bottom

I have already implemented a way in which when I click any of the rows of any of the table in the scrollview, that view disappears and another view zooms into its position.

I write the following code in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath in the middle table subview,

```
CGFloat xpos = self.view.frame.origin.x;
    CGFloat ypos = self.view.frame.origin.y;
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(xpos+100,ypos+150,5,5);
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Zoom" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(xpos,ypos,220,310);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [self.view addSubview:popContents.view];
```

popContents is the view I need to zoom into to the view previously occupied by that particular table view and that happens correctly.

However the problem that I am facing is that since there is another table subview in the side, if I increase the frame size to say 250 or so, the part of the zoomed in view gets hidden by the tableview on the side ( as its as if a part of the zoomed in view goes under the tableview on the side).

Is there anyway to correct this so that my zoomed in view would not get hidden by the tableviews on its sides?

I hope I have explained my problem correctly...

UPDATE:

Here is the code I am using for adding the subviews for the scrollview

```
// Scroll view
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 1000, 740)];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1000, 700);
scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];


aView = [[aViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"aViewController" bundle:nil];
aView.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 25, 220, 310);
[aView loadList:objPatients];
[scrollView addSubview:aView.view];

bView = [[bViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"bViewController" bundle:nil];
bView.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 350, 220, 310);
[bView loadList:objPatients];
[scrollView addSubview:bView.view];

cView = [[cViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"cViewController" bundle:nil];
cView.view.frame = CGRectMake(240, 25, 220, 310);
[cView loadList:objPatients];
[scrollView addSubview:cView.view];

dView = [[dViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"dViewController" bundle:nil];
enView.view.frame = CGRectMake(240, 350, 220, 310);
[enView loadList:objPatients];
[scrollView addSubview:dView.view];

eView = [[eViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"eViewController" bundle:nil];
eView.view.frame = CGRectMake(470, 25, 220, 310);
[eView loadList:objPatients];
[scrollView addSubview:eView.view];
```

say for example, I add the code for didSelectRowAtIndexPath in cViewController subview...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a guess since I would need to know how your table views are added to the scroll view, but the middle table view was probably added before the one on the side. Views are "stacked" in the order they're added with the last one on top. You'll need to get the scroll view to move the middle view to the front with this method

```
- (void)bringSubviewToFront:(UIView *)view
```

The best way to do that would be to create a protocol for the table views and make the scroll view the delegate. The method would be something like this

```
- (void) moveAViewToFront: (MyTableView *) aTableView
{
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront: aTableView.view];
}
```

You would then call the delegate method before setting up the animation.

**Edited**

After a little more thought I realized that the subviews have a reference to their superview so this bit of code should provide an idea on how to solve the problem. I created a test app which has a view controller which adds two sub views. The view controller header file is MoveSubviewViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MoveSubviewViewController : UIViewController
{
}

@end
```

and it's implementation is

```
#import "MoveSubviewViewController.h"
#import "MoveableSubview.h"

@implementation MoveSubviewViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        // Create two overlapping subviews. The blue subview will start at the top of
        //  the frame and extend down two thirds of the frame.
        CGRect superviewFrame = self.view.frame;
        CGRect view1Frame = CGRectMake( superviewFrame.origin.x, superviewFrame.origin.y,
                                       superviewFrame.size.width, superviewFrame.size.height * 2 / 3);
        MoveableSubview *view1 = [[MoveableSubview alloc] initWithFrame: view1Frame];
        view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        [self.view addSubview: view1];
        [view1 release];

        // The green subview will start one third of the way down the frame and
        //  extend all the to the bottom.
        CGRect view2Frame = CGRectMake( superviewFrame.origin.x,
                                       superviewFrame.origin.y + superviewFrame.size.height / 3,
                                       superviewFrame.size.width, superviewFrame.size.height * 2 / 3);
        MoveableSubview *view2 = [[MoveableSubview alloc] initWithFrame: view2Frame];
        view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        [self.view addSubview: view2];
        [view2 release];
    }

    @end
```

The subview class is MoveableSubview with another simple header

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MoveableSubview : UIView
{
}
@end
```

and implementation

```
#import "MoveableSubview.h"

@implementation MoveableSubview

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // Move this view to the front in the superview.
    [self.superview bringSubviewToFront: self];
}

@end
```

The thing to do is to add the

```
[self.superview bringSubviewToFront: self];
```

line before setting up the animation.

Comment: thanks for the pointing that out.. that is exactly what is happening.. I have edited my question to include the code.. so I am including the code for didSelectRowAtIndexPath in cViewController, where dViewController and eViewController are added after cViewController and hence they hide the zoom view.. I would like to know where should I add the code you mentioned and how do I call it? Should I write it in the cViewController or in the detailViewController of the split view?

Comment: Actually it's easier than I had originally thought. I'd forgotten that a subview automatically has a reference to it's superview so you don't need to use a protocol and delegate. I've edited my original answer to provide some sample code which should give you a solution.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the effort to solve my problem.. mine is a window based project and hence I am unable to use self.superview.. is there any other way I can do this in my case?

Comment: Give it a try anyway since in your case the scrollview is the  superview and the [a-d]ViewController's the are subviews.

Comment: I think I see the mistake in my answer: self refers to the view controller and self.view refers to it's view. Try [self.view.superview bringSubviewToFront: self];. Sorry for flubbing this one. I used views in my test and not view controllers.