# Using bringSubviewToFront in Ipad scrollview

Tags: ipad, uiscrollview, uisplitviewcontroller

In my Ipad app, I have a split view in which the detail view is a scroll view... 
I have 3 subviews to the scrollview which are tableviews... 
How do I use `- (void)bringSubviewToFront:(UIView *)view` to bring one of the subviews of the scrollview to the front when an action is performed? (since Views are "stacked" in the order they're added with the last one on top). Should I write the code in the subview or in the detailViewController and how do I call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write the code in the controller.

The controller should have access to the table views through `IBOutlet` properties. Or, if you didn't set them up using a nib, the controller should have been the one to create them.

If a button tap, for example, is responsible for showing a particular table view, the button's action handler method is where you call the `bringSubviewToFront:` method.

HOWEVER: It sounds like you have three table views on top of each other and are using `bringSubviewToFront:` to show the current one, and they are all inside a UIScrollView.

1. Each UITableView contains a UIScrollView. Don't put a scrollview inside a scrollview, they will fight over tracking touches and things will get weird. Just put the three table views inside a plain UIView.
2. Instead of bringSubviewToFront:, you ought to consider hiding the inactive views (call `setHidden:`). That way, the hidden views won't be considered part of the responder chain (won't get sent events).

Comment: thank you for the reply.. how would I call setHidden: to the other 2 table views? right now the action I perform is when a cell is selected in the middle table (middle subview).. so where do I write setHidden: to hide the other 2 tables ( other 2 subviews)?

Comment: It's hard to answer that question without knowing anything about your code. But it sounds like you want it to happen in the table view delegate method for did-select-cell.

Comment: here is a link to my original question from which this one came up - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668765/zooming-animation-problem-in-scrollview-ipad .from that, could you tell me which would be my tableview delegate?

Comment: You tell each table view which object is the delegate, and it gets method calls on events like selection or when a cell needs to be created.

Comment: No offense, but maybe you need to do a simpler project to learn this stuff well before you try to tackle something as complicated as this sounds.

Comment: none taken.. I am doing only few parts of the project like this animation effect while my mentor is doing the rest... thanks for your reply anyway.. will look into it...